# After zoom transition, the "camera" snaps back to where it was before zoom

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Though I have a JS fiddle [link here](http://jsfiddle.net/EM2c6/1/), it doesn't work in fiddle.

```
    <body>
        <script src="d3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
     <div id="graph"></div>
    <div id="UI">
    </div>
    </body>


   <script>
   function center() {
       var theGraph = d3.select("#container");
       theGraph.transition()
           .duration(750)
           .attr("transform", "translate(0, 0)scale(1)");
   }

   var svgWidth = 0;
   var svgHeight = 0;
   var startX = 0;
   var startY = 0;

   // code ran on load
   var svg = d3.select("#graph").append("svg").attr("id", "myGraph");
   // zoom handler
   svg.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw));
   // load data & assign to graph.
   // "container" holds all the SVG paths/groups
   svg.attr("width", 500).attr("height", 500).append("g").attr("id", "container");
    var container = svg.select("#container");
    container.append("circle").attr("cx", 25).attr("cy", 25).attr("r", 25).style("fill", "purple");

    // make the button
    d3.select("#UI").append("button").attr("type","button").attr("onclick","center()").html("Center");
    container.append("circle").attr("cx",100).attr("cy",50).attr("r", 10).style("fill", "blue");


   function redraw() {
       d3.select("#container").attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
   }

   </script>
```

The source code has to be saved as html and requires d3.js in the directory.

Clicking Center zooms out and translates the screen to (0,0). But if you drag/zoom the screen, it snaps back to the original view *before* the centering. A search seems to say that you need to reset the zoom object, but I don't see where I have one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do have a zoom object when you create `d3.behavior.zoom` here: `svg.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on('zoom', redraw)`.

As you have already found out, you have to reset it while transitioning back to `center`:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
        .on("zoom", redraw);

function center() {
   var theGraph = d3.select("#container");
   zoom.translate([0, 0]); // Resetting translate
   zoom.scale(1);          // Resetting scale
   theGraph.transition()
       .duration(750)
       .attr("transform", "translate(0, 0)scale(1)");
}

// ...
svg.call(zoom);
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EM2c6/2/

---

**Sidenote**: It wasn't working in `jsFiddle` previously because of this:

```
d3.select("#UI")
  .append("button")
  .attr("type","button")
  .attr("onclick", "center()") // <- This is not defined on the global scope
  .html("Center");
```

Using D3's `click` handler and not referencing to `center` function via a string fixed that problem:

```
d3.select("#UI")
  .append("button")
  .attr("type","button")
  .on("click",center)
  .html("Center");
```

Comment: Excellent answer. I didn't realize that ``d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw)`` created a 'zoom' object; I just thought that it was similar to .attr() in that it returned the base object (in this case, 'behavior' even though that's apparently not an object).

Comment: As for the sidenote, it's an error that happened simply because the example code is different from the original, wherein I create the graph from a JSON file, and have <script> and <body> in the same HTML file.

Comment: @Sky Glad to have helped. :)