# D3 v4: element 'snaps' to previous translate after programmatic transform

Tags: d3.js, svg

```
function zoomed() { svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform); }
var zoom = d3.zoom().on("zoom", zoomed);

var svgMain = d3.select('body').append('svg').call(zoom);
var svg = svgMain.append('g') // All the drawing done here
```

When I translate `svg` programmatically with `svg.call(zoom.translateBy, 100, 100)` then drag the element with the mouse, `svg` transform attribute snaps back to the value from before the drag.

It is almost as if the transform effected by `svg.call` is not stored or saved, and reverts to the transform stored in `d3.event.transform`.

[image: Logging d3.event.transform shows the problem]

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22420768/after-zoom-transition-the-camera-snaps-back-to-where-it-was-before-zoom) seems to be hitting on the same issue, though for v3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are applying the zoom behavior to two different nodes - `svgMain` and `svg`.

Try running `svgMain.call(zoom.translateBy, 100, 100)` instead of `svg.call(...)` and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: brilliant, I was using a code sample and missed this, and it's really hard to debug if you don't think of it.  Thank you.